# Java Code to search words in a sentence and if the words is present there it will display the sentence related to that words

Tags: java

I want a JAVA function which searches for a specific word in a sentence and if it is present there it will display the sentence which the words belong to.

Comment: Have you tried some code yet?  This looks like a requirements only question.

Answer (score 2):

You know what regular expressions are? Try them ans you will find an answer.[Regex Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use contains function 
Demo :

```
String sentence = "hello world";
String word = "hello";
if(sentence.contains(word)){
    System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

this will show 'hello world' if sentence contains 'world'